# Name produck does not appear when I call by date? how do you call it in blade in laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
Route::get('/zzz/{date}', function ($date) {
```

$ab = DB::table('permintaan_brgs')->where('users_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('tanggal','=',$date)->groupBy('nama_brg')->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%d %m %y')"))->get();
    return view('x', compact('ab', $ab));});

Comment: Which error u face?

Comment: @amindevloper 
Product name does not appear when I groupby date

Comment: You get the records after execute this query

Comment: @amindevloper 
when I DD the contents are null, can you help me?

Comment: Will you please share some more code?

Comment: @amindevloper yes i have two function, Route::get('/zzz', function () { 
  $a =App\permintaan_brg::where('users_id',Auth::user()->id)
  ->get()
  ->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->tanggal)->format('Y, m, d');
        }); 
   // dd($a);
    return view('surat.permintaanPerhari', compact('a', $a));
});

Comment: @amindevloper 
I can't display the item name based on the input date, please let me know